# Dynamic SQL Server Update Procedure gives Invalid column error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure that calls this stored procedure to update records in a table based on the parameters passed, but I get the following error.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Invalid column name '1.24483e+007'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Invalid column name '1.24101e+007'.

I can't figure what did I miss here?

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_UPDATEMEANSTDEV]
    @TableName Sysname,
    @Symbol NVARCHAR(50),
    @MeanLTD float, 
    @StdevLTD float, 
    @MaxLTD float,
    @MeanYTD float, 
    @StdevYTD float, 
    @MaxYTD float
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
        ' SET LTD_MEAN = ' + QUOTENAME(@MeanLTD) + 
        ',YTD_MEAN = ' + QUOTENAME(@MeanYTD) +
        ',LTD_MAX = ' + QUOTENAME(@MaxLTD) +
        ',YTD_MAX = ' + QUOTENAME(@MaxYTD) +
        ',LTD_STDEV = ' + QUOTENAME(@StdevLTD) +
        ',YTD_STDEV = ' + QUOTENAME(@StdevYTD) +
        + ' WHERE (SYMBOL = @SYMBOL)';

    EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql]  @sqlCommand,
                  N'@Symbol nvarchar(50)', @Symbol = @Symbol;
END
```

Comment: Should you use `QUOTENAME` for values? Wouldn't that quote the parameter to be used as a name (such as a table or column name)?

Comment: Please provide your `QUOTENAME` function definition, as well as sample input that yields your error.

Comment: can you print the query inside  @sqlCommand and post here?

Comment: QuoteName is an inbuilt function LDMJoe. If I don't use it I get the following error: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 19
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: @SqlCommand Query: UPDATE [VNASAAIT] SET LTD_MEAN = [1.2],YTD_MEAN = [1.2],LTD_MAX = [1.2],YTD_MAX = [1.2],LTD_STDEV = [1.2],YTD_STDEV = [1.2] WHERE (SYMBOL = @SYMBOL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, that you're wrapping up your values in square brackets, which is not correct and your float numbers are threated as columns (well, any object in DB) and of course these don't exist there. This should be correct:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_UPDATEMEANSTDEV]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName Sysname,
    @Symbol NVARCHAR(50),
    @MeanLTD FLOAT, 
    @StdevLTD FLOAT, 
    @MaxLTD FLOAT,
    @MeanYTD FLOAT, 
    @StdevYTD FLOAT, 
    @MaxYTD FLOAT
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    -- DECLARE @DATEVARCHAR NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'
        SET LTD_MEAN = @MeanLTD
          , YTD_MEAN = @MeanYTD
          , LTD_MAX = @MaxLTD
          , YTD_MAX = @MaxYTD
          , LTD_STDEV = @StdevLTD
          , YTD_STDEV = @StdevYTD
        WHERE SYMBOL = @SYMBOL';

    EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @sqlCommand
      , N '@Symbol NVARCHAR(50), @MeanLTD FLOAT, @StdevLTD FLOAT, @MaxLTD FLOAT, @MeanYTD FLOAT, @StdevYTD FLOAT, @MaxYTD FLOAT'
      , @Symbol
      , @MeanLTD
      , @StdevLTD
      , @MaxLTD
      , @MeanYTD
      , @StdevYTD
      , @MaxYTD;
END
```

Comment: I think the other parameter values need to be assigned, similarly to @Symbol.

Comment: Not necessarily. They should be picked up in order, which is defined in parameters declaration.

Comment: Yes, it must.  `Must pass parameter number 4 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.`

Comment: I'm used not to pass these and it's always working. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Perfect Evaldas; Worked on first try itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `QUOTENAME` functon. You cannot use it cover values. It is supposed to escape the `reserved keywords , symbols and space` in any sql `objects`.

Now the values will be considered as `Column names` in `update` statement since it is enclosed with `square brackets` that is the reason for error.
Example `[1.2]` will be parsed as a column present in `VNASAAIT` table

```
 DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
        ' SET LTD_MEAN = ' + cast(@MeanLTD as varchar(50)) + 
        ',YTD_MEAN = ' + cast(@MeanYTD as varchar(50)) +
        ',LTD_MAX = ' + cast(@MaxLTD as varchar(50)) +
        ',YTD_MAX = ' + cast(@MaxYTD as varchar(50)) +
        ',LTD_STDEV = ' + cast(@StdevLTD as varchar(50)) +
        ',YTD_STDEV = ' + cast(@StdevYTD as varchar(50)) +
        + ' WHERE (SYMBOL = @SYMBOL)';
```

Comment: This will not work. You should get error that nvarchar cannot be converted to float.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas - Yep missed it